# Python Flask SQLalchemy sqlite3 prevent SQL injections in Database search

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I would like to know how I should change my code to prevent it from Injections:

```
import sqlite3

def search_in_database(column,searched_data):
    con = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    
    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT
                        id
                        FROM
                        My_library
                        WHERE
                        {column} LIKE '%{searched_data}%'
                        ;""")
    all = [i for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    return all
```

I found code in web which gives an example of how to do it:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
# Create a connection conn
stmt = text("""SELECT * FROM users
               WHERE user = :username AND password = :password""")
conn.execute(stmt, prams={"username": "foo", "password": "bar"})
```

but In my HTML file I would like to give to user possibility to choose the:

Place where he wants to search in Titles, authors, published_dates,isbn, language...

and when he choose where He what to search then he types the query.

How to do it in this case, avoiding Injections?

My data base:

```
class My_library(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    authors = db.Column(db.String(100))
    published_date = db.Column(db.Integer)
    isbn_or_identifier = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    page_count = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    language = db.Column(db.String(3))
    image_links = db.Column(db.String(500))
```

I also added validators:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField,StringField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError,DataRequired,Length, URL
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField,IntegerField,DateField,IntegerField, URLField

class AddRecValidators(FlaskForm):

    title = StringField(label=('Title:'),validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1,max=50)])
    authors = StringField(label=('Authors:'),validators=[Length(min=1,max=100)])
    published_date = IntegerField(label=('Published date:'),validators=[Length(min=1,max=4)])
    isbn_or_identifier = IntegerField(label=('ISBN:'),validators=[Length(min=1,max=15)])
    page_count = IntegerField(label=('Page count:'),validators=[ Length(min=1,max=10000)])
    language = StringField(label=('Language:'),validators=[ Length(min=1,max=3)])
    image_links = URLField(label=('Image links:'))
    
    submit = SubmitField(label=('Add to library'))
```

Thanks for help in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlalchemy to build the query. For example:

```
q = My_library.__table__.select().where(
    My_library.__table__.c.title == "The searched title"
)
```

but that's not exactly what you wanted. You can also address the columns by their names like this:

```
q = My_library.__table__.select().where(
    My_library.__table__.c["title"] == "The searched title"
)
# or
q = My_library.__table__.select().where(
    My_library.__table__.c["title"].like("%The searched title%")
)
```

Therefore you can do this:

```
q = My_library.__table__.select().where(
    My_library.__table__.c[column].like(f"%{searched_data}%")
)
cursor.execute(q)
```

In case you only want the ID, you would do this:

```
q = sqlalchemy.select([My_library.__table__.c.id]).where(
    My_library.__table__.c[column].like(f"%{searched_data}%")
)
# you can print(q) to see what it constructed
cursor.execute(q)
```

That was SQLAlchemy Query Language. You are using ORM. I suggest you read-up something about a session in flask first.

It is still possible to get to the column-name related attribute and I am not sure this is the most efficient way:

```
q = session.query(My_library.id).filter(
    getattr(My_library, column).like(f"%{searched_data}%"),
)
```